# Gradle sync failed: com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.issues.SdkPlatformNotFoundException: Module: 'app' platform 'android-29' not found

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, android-studio-4.1

Installed Android 4.1 on Ubuntu 20.04. Getting the following error:

`Gradle sync failed: com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.issues.SdkPlatformNotFoundException: Module: 'app' platform 'android-29' not found.`

On opening the SDK manager I get the following screen:
[image: android studio screenshot]

I also executed
`$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`

How to fix this?

------ edit ---------

This is what shows in the SDK Platforms tab. Unchecking the "Hide Obsolete Packages" doesn't change anything.

[image: Sdk platforms]

Answer (score 48):

As the error is saying. Install the SDK Platform with API Level 29. YOu need to switch to the tab " SDK Platforms and install the right API Level:

[image]

-----------edit--------------

maybe you changed accidently your SDK location.

Mine is on `C:\Users\elmo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

Pay attention: using it on windows.

Comment: Edited the original post with the output for "SDK Ploatforms" tab. How to get API Level 29?

Comment: You can find SDK Platforms under File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings  (or use the search to find it)

Comment: With newer versions of Android Studio SDK Manager has a button on the toolbar (way top right next to the magnifying glass, it's a grey cube with a blue arrow next to it). It just opens the location @MadMac explained above. When you select a package you don't have installed, you'll see a download arrow to the left of the checkbox, click that and acknowledge the download in the next popup and it'll download it for you.

Answer (score 10):

go to the "sdk platforms" you can find it by click on navigate->find anywhere than enter "sdk"
than what you need is to find the api level you need (29 in your case) and check the box near it.

Comment: thanks, response was simple and easy to apply

Answer (score 7):

Go to  File -> Project Structure -> Modules(Properties Tab) -> Change the compile Sdk Version and Build Tools Version to the the latest version available at the time
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdTRQ.png)