# Why don't I have the option to create a new activity in Android Studio 4.1?

Tags: android

What I see when trying to add a new activity to a project:

[image]

Comment: You can try to Sync Project with Gradle files. It helped to solve [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55537030/9972209)

Comment: Thanks, I think that's got me on the right track. There's something wrong with my Gradle sync. I had an out of date SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The root of my problem was an out of date SDK. This can be updated by searching for SDK Platform and following the instructions here:

[Gradle sync failed: com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.issues.SdkPlatformNotFoundException: Module: 'app' platform 'android-29' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64677522/gradle-sync-failed-com-android-tools-idea-gradle-project-sync-idea-issues-sdkpl)

Update that, select synch project with gradle files from the file menu, and you're good to go

Answer (score 0):

Try to do **invalidate Cache/ Restart**. If this not work try out **Sync Project With Gradle files**